# How do I graph a circle with n number of slices of even area in Pyplot?

Tags: python

I need to write a function called circ_sectors(n) where it displays a circle with n number of slices.

For instance, circ_sectors(7) would give me 7 equal slices of the circle.[image]

So far, I've only been able to graph the circle.

```
def circ_sectors(n):
   angle = np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 100)
   radius = 1
   x = [radius * math.cos(x) for x in angle]
   y = [radius * math.sin(x) for x in angle]

   plt.axis('equal')
   plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Do you mean like a radar chart?

Comment: Yes, "slices" is ambiguous. Sectors or segments is more precise.

Comment: Yes I meant sectors, I was thinking in terms of pie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already used the cos and sin functions.
Now just reuse these to find the endpoints at the circle?!

```
for i in range ( n ):
  plt.plot( [0, ( math.cos( i * (2*math.pi) / n ) )], [ 0, ( math.sin( i * (2*math.pi) / n ) ) ] )
```

This paints the circle you posted already.

Is this what you want/need?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't use any other packages besides random, matplotlib, math, and numpy